# Считывания ввода с консоли JS/blessed

Tags: javascript, консоль

Столкнулся с необходимостью считывания данных с консоли (лабораторная работа), знаю что это возможно реализовать с помощью библиотеки blessed, но в документации большинство информации о стилизации, возможно кто-то знает как считать одну строку? Или возможно есть способ выполнить эту функции без использования blessed?

Comment: Что за консоль имеется ввиду?

Comment: консоль разработчика в VS Code/Терминал